# Open accordion panel with a link

Tags: javascript

I need to add a link in the first accordion panel to open the second accordion panel.

```
<div class="dt-sc-toggle-frame-set  type2">
    <h5 class="dt-sc-toggle-accordion"><a href="#">Accordion1</a></h5>
    <div class="dt-sc-toggle-content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="block">
            Accordion panel 1
            <a href="#accordion2" class="dt-sc-button small orange">NEXT<span class="fa fa-home"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5 class="dt-sc-toggle-accordion" id="accordion2"><a href="#">Accordion2</a></h5>
    <div class="dt-sc-toggle-content" style="display: none;">
        <div class="block">
            Accordion panel 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5 class="dt-sc-toggle-accordion active"><a href="#">Accordion3</a></h5>
    <div class="dt-sc-toggle-content" style="display: block;">
        <div class="block">
            Accordion panel 3
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide information about what implementation of accordion do you use. (Bootstrap, jQuery, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Is there any accompanying Javascript that makes any of the Accordions semi-functional? Is there some CSS to go along with this HTML? It seems like this question is a bit incomplete.

Comment: I'm using the accordion from this wordpress theme http://wedesignthemes.com/themes/dt-priority/shortcodes/accordions-toggles/